# Incorrect host name Android studio

Tags: android

I have already install Android studio in my PC but when I create a new project the following message is shown

"
Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'.

Please ensure the host name is correct. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in Android Studio or Gradle.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) "

Now What is the problem and how can I solve it.

Comment: Hostname resolves just fine for me.  Are you behind a proxy?  Is it configured?  Can you pull up that address in a web browser?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. To fix the problem do this:

1. Go to Configuration ---> HTTP Proxy
2. Select "Auto-detect proxy settings".
3. Click -- OK

Hope this works for you.
Good Luck !